# Custom Woocommerce cart add has wrong item count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to add a product to a woocommerce cart with a wp_loaded action after I submit a custom add to cart form.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'custom_process_form' );
function custom_process_form(){       
    global $woocommerce;
    if(isset($_POST["addcoupon"])){           
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
            if($key=="addcoupon"){
                    continue;
            }

            $valarr=explode("_",$key);

            if ($valarr[0]=="couponid"){
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($valarr[1],1);
                $count++;
            }               
        } 
    }       
}
```

It works fine except when it first loads, the cart thinks that I added 2 products instead of 1. For some reason, its running `WC_Cart->calculate_totals()` twice and `$this->cart_contents_count` is not reset to zero, so the quantity gets twice. (When I reload the page, the cart shows the correct number of items)

What is the correct way to add a product with a custom form? I can't find any examples of this. Am I using the wrong action?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented on my own install and can confirm the same is happening to me. For me `calculate_totals()` is getting called once by the add to cart process and then again by the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin getting the cart from the session. Do you have this plugin installed?

That said I don't think calling `calculate_totals()` is really a problem. The real problem is that `$this->cart_contents_count` should reset. I got around this by adding this code to `functions.php`.

```
function reset_quantities( $cart )
{
     $cart->cart_contents_count = 0;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'reset_quantities' );
```

**EDIT**: Actually that doesn't work for me. The reason is that the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin is calling `calculate_totals()` through the 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' action. This prevents other functions on the same action from firing. This is mentioned at this ticket.  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17817

Try this instead

```
function reset_quantities( $cart_object )
{
    $cart           = $cart_object->get_cart();          
    $cart_object->cart_contents_count = 0;

    foreach ( $cart as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $cart_object->cart_contents_count  += $values['quantity'];
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'reset_quantities', 10, 1 );
```

**EDIT2** I just looked at the latest commit of WooCommerce on Github and `calculate_totals()` has changed a lot. You may want to try downloading that to see if it solves your problem.